# How could I find out *which file* a line of text on a webpage is from?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using Chrome's [Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) extension, but there is this block of text I'd like to edit, which I am obviously able to do in the browser. But as parts of an app of mine was outsourced, I'm unable to find out exactly which file (html or php) contains the block of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using a tool like [Agent Randsack](http://mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) to find the block of text in the source code. Once it's in the browser, there's no telling what block of server-side code actually contains it. It might even be coming out of a database.

Comment: yeah, best to just use grep, or any other tool that will search the content of files.  Other than that, there really isn't much else you can do.  The text could also be pulled from the database, if your project uses one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't. You'll have to grep the webserver for the html or php code that contains the text. The webserver generates the html for you from the source files, so from the client perspective there's no way to figure this out unless you somehow add debug info from the server side.